# Chat mySQL table, select statement to find unique conversations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of chat messages:

id, nToUserID, nFromUserID, strMessage

I'm trying find unique occurrences of messages between two users. NOT all the messages, just, is there at least one message to a user or from a user. I'll use this to show a list of "conversations" which could then be clicked to view the full chat thread.

I tried using a DISTINCT select, but that appeared to still give me multiple records between the same users.

I thought about a left JOIN, but again that appears to give me multiple or empty records.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select distinct least(nToUserID, nFromUserID), greatest(nToUserID, nFromUserID)
from t;
```

If you want the *other* users, then use:

```
select distinct (case when nToUserID = ? then nFromUserID else nToUserID end) as userID
from t
where ? in (nToUserID, nFromUserID);
```

The `?` is the id of the user you want the connections to.

Comment: I sort of just want a single column with the users ID that the messages are between... always the OTHER users ID... but I could send a message to them.. OR they could send a message to me... but that would still just give me one row with only the id of the user that am interacting with

Comment: @NathanLeggatt . . . That was not clear from your question, but the answer is somewhat similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count function to get the unique id pairs and their respective number of conversations.

```
SELECT nFromUserId, nToUserId, count(id) FROM `table` GROUP BY nFromUserId, nToUserId
```

Though this doesn't work if you need to count nFromUserId and nToUserId interchangeably.